# PHP/JAVASCRIPT: Is it possible to print only the selected table in the printer?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, printing

im just wondering if im going to search a data then will print only the table not including the search box and the submitt button. it is possible to do that?

Comment: see some link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18248809/window-print-print-all-div-content-withot-scrollbar

Comment: more link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255291/print-the-contents-of-a-div

Answer (score 0):

Yes, no PHP or JavaScript required, just CSS: You provide a *print style sheet* that hides all elements except the ones you want to print:

```
@media print {
    /* ...these rules only apply when printing, use them to hide search boxes
       and such... */
}
```